# Changing a React State Object with Spread Operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to validate a form before submting it,and I created an object of possible errors, but when try to change the value of each key it behaves weirdly...

```
const inialState = {
  name: "",
  email: "",
  message: "",
};
const errors = {
  name: false,
  email: false,
  message: false,
};
const Contact = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(inialState);
  const [error, setError] = useState(errors);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!validateSubmit()) {
      return;
    }
  };
  const handleChange = (e) =>
    setValues({ ...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  function validateSubmit(e) {
    let response = true;
    if (!values.name) {
      setError({ ...error, name: true });
      response = false;
    }
    if (!values.email) {
      setError({ ...error, email: true });
      response = false;
    }
    if (!values.message) {
      setError({ ...error, [errors.message]: true });// I also tried this way =(
      response = false;
    }
    console.log(error);
    return response;
  }
...
return(
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}> //its a simple button type="submit"
...
```

The *validateSubmit* function is called by the Submit button.

[image: This is what It's shown when I submit the form and its supossed to change the state values...]

Comment: Should it be `[values.message]: true` instead of `[errors.message]: true`?

Comment: I suggest you extract the error in a new object and later at the very end before the return sentence assign the error result object to the state like this: setError(errorResult)

Comment: @Rafael Tavares , no because the values is the object state of all of the form fields

Comment: Where does `values` come from? Where is `validateSubmit` called? Where are you doing that `console.log` whose output you've shown? The parts of the code you've shown so far seem more or less reasonable.

Comment: It really should be `{ ...error, message: true }` not `{ ...error, [errors.message]: true }` to signify that `message` has an error.

Comment: @Bergi I added almost the whole component, only left out the irrelevant components parts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs when you call `setError` multiple times from `validateSubmit`. Only the last value will win - in your example that's the one that added `"false": true` (because `errors.message` that you used as a property name is `false`).

Notice that `setError` does [not (synchronously, or at all) update the `error` constant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54069253/1048572), it only changes the component state and causes it to re-render with a new value. The `{...errror, …}` always did refer to the original value of `error`. To avoid this, you can

- either aggregate the errors into a single value before calling `setError` once

  ```
  function validateSubmit(e) {
    let newError = error;
    if (!values.name) {
      newError = { ...newError, name: true };
    }
    if (!values.email) {
      newError = { ...newError, email: true };
    }
    if (!values.message) {
      newError = { ...newError, message: true };
    }
    console.log(error, newError);
    setError(newError);
    return newError != error;
  }
  ```
- or use the callback version of `setError` that will execute the updates in a row and always pass the latest state in each callback as an argument:

  ```
  function validateSubmit(e) {
    let response = true;
    if (!values.name) {
      setError(oldError => ({ ...oldError, name: true }));
      response = false;
    }
    if (!values.email) {
      setError(oldError => ({ ...oldError, email: true }));
      response = false;
    }
    if (!values.message) {
      setError(oldError => ({ ...oldError, message: true }));
      response = false;
    }
    console.log(error);
    return response;
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks man! I knew I was missing the callback of the same object. Just a note, theres a parentheses missing. setError((error) => ({ ...error, name: true })).

Comment: Quick question, why does my controled inputs works just fine (const handleChange = (e) =>
    setValues({ ...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });), but these guys won't? I mean like, isn't it the same concept?

Comment: Because you call `setValues` only once, before the component is rerendered and a new `handleChange` function is created and attached as the handler, that will close over the new value of `const values`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is useReducer() to modify only portions of the state. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer.

```
const errors = {
     name: false,
     email: false,
     message: false,
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
    return {...state, ...action};
};

const [error, updateError] = useReducer(reducer,
    errors
);

function validateSubmit(e) {
    let response = true;
    if (!values.name) {
      updateError({name: true });
      response = false;
    }
    if (!values.email) {
      updateError({email: true });
      response = false;
    }
    if (!values.message) {
      updateError({message: true });
      response = false;
    }
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Your `reducer` doesn't "*modify only portions of the state*", instead it completely throws away the previous state. It's not clear how that is better than using `useState`

Comment: Why are you destructuring `{ data }`? You never pass an object with a `data` property as an action.

Comment: Shouldn't have copy pasted old code, thanks @Bergi